# JavaScript : how to display list from this api data

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, api

I'm currently working on a project where I take an API from a site, and display it on my webpage.

```
{
  "data": [{
  "truckplanNo":"TCTTV___0D010013",
  "truckplanType":"COLLECTION",
  "planArriveOriginTime":"2020-12-01T01:30:00.000000+07:00",
  "planDepartOriginTime":"2020-12-01T02:00:00.000000+07:00",
  "actualReleaseTime":"2020-11-30T21:46:56.000607+07:00",
  "jobSheetLine":2,
  "truckType":"10W",
  "truckLicense":"0717349/108",
  "orderLine":7,
  "updatedTimestamp":"2020-12-01T10:07:38.000575+07:00",
  "routeCategoryDesc":"SUPPLIER TO PLANT",
  "cbmLoadEff":37.80270691994573015,
  "flagReprint":false"
}]
}
```

How to fetch this data to show in html only text?

Comment: use JSON.parse()  https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_parse.asp . Refer this too:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37844560/how-to-parse-nested-json-in-javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
const parsed = JSON.parse(json); // json is that json text
const data = parsed.data; // To get data key from json
data.forEach(cur => {
  console.log(cur); // This will print objects in data array one by one
});
```

That's it!